# why my code not working? (using selectize.js)

Tags: selectize.js

I want to use selectize.js , but my code not working?
running this code shows standard(normal) select element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="selectize.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="selectize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#colors').selectize();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <select id="colors">
       <option value="1">Red</option>
       <option value="2">Green</option>
       <option value="3">Blue</option>
   </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved , i must use lower version of jquery :

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code by adding class

```
<select id="colors" class="seletizeData" data-placeholder="Colors">
       <option value="1">Red</option>
       <option value="2">Green</option>
       <option value="3">Blue</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Why should that make a difference?